# Find all $x$ so $\frac{1^2+2^2+\cdots+x^2}{x}$ is a perfect square...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, means, sums-of-squares

Find all $x$ so $\dfrac{1^2+2^2+\cdots+x^2}{x}$ is a perfect square...

Clearly 1 is solution, but I have to show that there is an infinity... I see that this happens when the numbers $1,2,...,x$ have a whole quadratic root. Am I on the right road?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main result is:

$$1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots + x^2=\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}$$

So you need $\frac{(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}=y^2$ for some $y$.

Or:

$$2x^2+3x+1 = 6y^2$$

From here, we are essentially going to "complete the square" on the left side.

Multiply both sides by $8$ and you get:

$$16x^2+24x+8=(4x+3)^2-1=48y^2$$

So you need infinitely many solutions to:

$$(4x+3)^2-48y^2=1$$

So you need to know how to solve [Pell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) from here.

The generally positive solution to the equation $u^2-48y^2=1$ can be written as:

$$u+y\sqrt{48}=(7+\sqrt{48})^k$$

For any positive integer $k$.

You should be able to prove with induction that infinitely many $u$ have $u\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

The recursive sequence of values of $u$ is $u_0=1,u_1=7$ and $u_{n+1}=14u_n-u_{n-1}$. You can show that $u_k\equiv 3\pmod 4$ when $k$ is odd. The next answers after $x=1$ are $x=337$ and $x=65521$.

Comment: But the OP has squares, whereas you have cubes... Is it a consequence of a later edit?

Comment: @b00nheT Where do I have cubes?

Comment: $"\frac{(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}=y^2$" Isn't there missing a $x$ in the beginning?

Comment: Oh gosh. It's only a typo on the third summand. It should be $3^2$. For some reason I thought you were summing cubes all the way.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews in the first line

Comment: @DanielAlberten He divided by $x$.

Comment: @b00nheT Ah, yes, typo.

Comment: Yeah. My fault! Sorry. Great answer btw!

Comment: Extremly beautiful answer!!

Comment: It's a pretty common trick for solving equations like $ax^2+bx+c=dy^2$ to reduce it to a Pell equation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you find the answers after 1?

Comment: As I said above, you need to know how to solve Pell equations. There is a general technique to solving $u^2-Dv^2=1$ where $D$ is not a square. @DanielAlberten

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes I know, but it arives at $n$ not whole, is there a easyer way then just ckecking over and over again?

Comment: What is $n$? I've laid out exactly how I got the values, if you read carefully. @DanielAlberten

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you prove that $u_{n+1}=14u_n-u_{n-1}$?

Comment: Do you know that $u_{k}=\frac{1}{2}\left((7+\sqrt{48})^k+(7-\sqrt{48})^k\right)$? Then $u_k$ satisfies a recurrence of the above sort. @DanielAlberten